# Getting rid of an extrusion

Tags: modeling

I'm new to blender and I wanted to make a support beam for this roof but I don't want the beam to extrude beyond the roof and just end at the base of the roof. How would I go about removing the top portion of this cylinder?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your cylinder a *Boolean* modifier with the plane as *Object*:

[image]

Comment: if you have problems as i had with moonboots solution and it cuts off the wrong half: select your plane, TAB -> edit mode -> mesh -> normals -> flip so get you get the right one  ;)

Comment: and i always thought boolean with planes won't work because it needs volume...+1

Comment: @ Chris, like you I was not sure but it worked  ;)

Comment: Blender is just awesome. I am so often positively surprised what it is capable of....faszinating.

Answer (score 2):

With these snap settings:

[image]

you can do this:

[image]